# reload scripts of controls with change visibility

Tags: javascript, reload, visible

i have a control that has some checkboxes and some javascript functions.
i use it in some pages and it work correctly.
in one case, i use it in a page that have two table and table that has this control in pageload is invisible and after some operation, i change its visibility TRUE. but scripts of control don't load, and i have error on this page : 'Object expected'.
in source, there are not scripts of control.
how can i reload scripts of control after change visibility?

Comment: show us the relevant parts of your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my control was in a table that i changed visibilty with mytable.visible = false; or mytable.visible = true. on page_load mytable's visible = false and scripts of control dont load. then when i change visiblility , its scripts don,t load.
Now i change visibility by style='display:none' or style='display:block'. In this case scripts of control load on page_load.